# "Move to namespace..." is not in "Quick Actions and Refactorings..." (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, visual-studio-2019

"Move to namespace..." in Visual Studio 2019 is very useful for me.
Most of the time, it is in "Quick Actions and Refactorings...", but sometimes it disappears.

Why does "Move to namespace..." disappear? How to trigger it under this circumstance?

[image]